# Java datetime inconsistent between local application and Jenkins deployment

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, jenkins, time

I am receiving a date time as a string into my application. There I need to extract the hour so it can be written to a file along with some other stuff. For my unit test the string will look like this

```
2019-10-26T00:00:00+01:00
```

The code I use to extract the hour is this

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public static int extractHour(String dateInString) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ");
    DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(dateInString);
    return dateTime.getHourOfDay();
}
```

My test passes locally with expected hour 00 and actual hour 00 but when I deploy through Jenkins the actual hour is showing as 23 and my expected is 00.

Comment: Time zone or offset issue... What's the locale of your local system and what's the one of your deployment target?

Comment: You have to specify the Local in your formatter, also I would suggest to use `java.time` instead of joda

Comment: @YCF_L Specifying the timezone in the formatter worked for me, put it as an answer if you like and i will accept

Comment: it is nice to hear this, It was a shot from my side :) , I will let you post the answer and I will UV :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don’t instruct Joda-Time otherwise, `formatter.parseDateTime()` parses into a `DateTime` in your default time zone.

So if for example your local time zone is set to Europe/Dublin or Europe/London, the result of parsing will be a `DateTime` of `2019-10-26T00:00:00.000+01:00` (because October 26 was the last day with summer time (DST) in those time zones) and the hour of day will be 0 as you expected. And if the time zone setting of your Jenkins server is UTC — that’s pretty commonplace — your string is parsed into `2019-10-25T23:00:00.000Z` there. And the hour of day will be 23, obviously.

If you want the offset from your string to be retained in the `DateTime`, the fix is:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ")
            .withOffsetParsed();
```

However, think twice. The hour of day only makes sense relative to the offset. In the night where summer time ended you could have strings of `2019-10-27T01:00:00+01:00` and an hour later when the clocks are changed, `2019-10-27T01:00:00+00:00`. Both strings have hour of day of 1, but there’s an hour between them. Do you really want the same result? What if one day you get a string of `2020-02-16T00:00:00-05:00`?

**Edit:**

> What would you suggest rather than using withOffsetParsed()[?]

I first of all suggest that you decide what result you want for strings with different offsets, for example `2020-03-06T18:00:00+05:30` and `2020-04-18T04:00:00-08:00`. You ought to know that better than I.

A generally recommended practice for handling time across offsets is to handle everything in UTC. This can be a special case of the solution you already found and mentioned in a comment, specifying time zone on the formatter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ")
            .withZoneUTC();
```

This guarantees a consistent result, apparently the same result that you already got on the Jenkins server. So 23 in your example.

PS If this is new code, you probably shouldn’t use Joda-Time. [The Joda-Time homepage](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) says:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to `java.time` (JSR-310).

Comment: What would you suggest rather than using withOffsetParsed()